# Get Parent row with child and condition

Tags: mysql, nested, parent-child

I have a table called ticket:

```
ticket (idTicket, title , message , parentTicket, lastdate, status)
```

status got default value : open , once i (mod) reply is set to replied

I'm trying to get active ticket mean with status open (new created and last user reply)

Example:

```
13 , 'Title 1' , 'msg Title1' , NULL , 'open'
14 , 'Title 2' , 'msg Title2' , NULL , 'open'
15 , 'reply Title 2' , 'reply msg Title2' , 14 , 'replied'
16 , 'Title 3' , 'msg Title3' , NULL ,'open'
17 ,  'reply Title 3' , 'reply msg Title3' , 16 , 'replied'
```

Normally I should list only ticket id 13

my 2 query idea but no luck

1/

```
SELECT *
FROM ticket AS parent LEFT JOIN
     ticket AS child 
     ON child.parentTicket = parent.idTicket
WHERE parent.parentTicket IS NULL and child.status ="open"
ORDER BY parent.idTicket, child.idTicket;
```

2/

```
Select t1.idTicket ,t2.parentTicket
from ticket t1 inner join
     ticket t2
     on (t1.idTicket != t2.parentTicket)
where t1.status ="open" and t2.parentTicket is null
Group by idTicket
```

3/

```
Select a.idTicket ,a.titleTicket,a.parentTicket
from ticket a
where not exists (select null from ticket b where a.parentTicket!=b.parentTicket) 
and a.status='open'
```

Answer (score 1):

To return open "root" tickets that don't have any child ticket... that is, a row from `ticket` that has `NULL` for `parentTicket`, and has `status='open'`, and for which a child ticket does not exist, you could use an *anti-join* pattern:

```
 SELECT p.*
   FROM ticket p
   LEFT
   JOIN ticket c
     ON c.parentTicket = p.idTicket
  WHERE p.parentTicket IS NULL
    AND p.status = 'open'
    AND c.parentTicket IS NULL
```

The *anti-join* is an outer join, with a predicate in the WHERE clause that excludes rows that had a match. That's basically saying get all the open "root" tickets, along with any matching child rows. The trick is the last predicate,  `c.parentTicket IS NULL`... any matching child rows are guaranteed to have non-NULL values (due to the JOIN predicate), so this excludes any rows that had a matching child.

This is equivalent to a query with a `NOT EXISTS (subquery)` predicate. This is perhaps easier to understand:

```
 SELECT p.*
   FROM ticket p
  WHERE p.parentTicket IS NULL
    AND p.status = 'open'
    AND NOT EXISTS
        ( SELECT 1
            FROM ticket c
           WHERE c.parentTicket = p.idTicket
        )
 ;
```

Both of these queries will return row with `idTicket=13`.

[SQL Fiddle demonstration here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/393b7/1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/393b7/1)

BUT... while those queries return the specified row, and are sufficient for the sample data that was provided in the question, I don't think this satisfies the *entirety* of the specification. There was a bit in the question about "*last user reply*", but beyond that, the specification is rather sparse. No example data illustrating which rows should be (and should not be) returned. What if there are multiple replies, or a reply to a reply, and what about the status of the reply, and the authorship, etc.

Or, maybe these queries are sufficient, or at least enough to get you headed in the right direction.

Comment: thank you spencer , actually i got the trick , but there is a small bug , here is it:  13 , 'Title 1' , 'msg Title1' , NULL , 'open'
14 , 'Title 2' , 'msg Title2' , NULL , 'open'
15 , 'reply Title 2' , 'reply msg Title2' , 14 , 'replied'
16 , 'Title 3' , 'msg Title3' , NULL ,'open'
17 ,  'reply Title 3' , 'reply msg Title3' , 16 , 'replied'
18 , 'Title 4', 'msg title 4', Null , 'open'
19 , 'reply title 3','msg reply title 3' , 16 , 'open'  , normally it should list ticket id : 13 18 and 16 but only show 13 and 18

Comment: ok i edited your query , SELECT p.*,c.idTicket
       FROM ticket p
       LEFt
       JOIN ticket c
         ON c.parentTicket = p.idTicket
      where p.status ="open"
        AND c.parentTicket IS NULL
       
     , however last row dont show root ticket id...(which is 16 ) it show 19